# Why won't this code compile if I don't use a reference?

Tags: c++, reference

I have a function that operates on an `std::ifstream`:

```
#include <fstream>

void handle(std::ifstream file) {
  // Do things
}

int main() {
  std::ifstream file("x.txt");
  handle(file);
}
```

This code gives me [this](http://pastebin.com/xd3vL26b) error.

However, if I make `handle`'s single parameter a reference (`void handle(std::ifstream& file`), the code compiles without warnings.

Why?

Comment: Have you read the error?

Comment: @KerrekSB yes, as a matter of fact I am still reading the error.

Comment: Uhm, why did you reedit? My edit made your question look more beautiful and improves reading fluency.

Comment: @cad sorry about that, I didn't see it was you who made that edit. I said "this code" as a reference to the code above. I don't understand why you linked "this code" to the error message. Feel free to revert.

Comment: Oh, no, your totally right, I thought the link refers to code indeed. My fault, sorry. Edited again, BTW.

Comment: @cad that looks better, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter is *passed by value*, which requires the argument to be copied.
**However**, `std::ifstream` does not provide a copy constructor.

From [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/):

```
ifstream (const ifstream&) = delete;
```